# get_categories for custom post type and filter by custom taxonomy (brand) and list child categories of a defined category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, archives

Thanks to @MikeSchinkel I have the following code:

```
$term = get_query_var('term');
    $brand = get_term_by('slug',$term,'brands'); // This here just to illustrate
    $categories = get_cross_referenced_terms(array(
    'post_type'        => 'Products',
    'taxonomy'         => 'category',
    'related_taxonomy' => 'brands',
    'term_id'          => $brand->term_id
  ));
```

which uses the following function:

```
// query to get categories for a specific tag
function get_cross_referenced_terms($args) {
  global $wpdb;
  $args = wp_parse_args($args,array(
    'post_type'        => 'Products',
    'taxonomy'         => 'category',
    'related_taxonomy' => 'brands',
    'term_id'          => 0,
  ));
  extract($args);
  $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  {$wpdb->terms}.*,
  COUNT(*) AS post_count
FROM
  {$wpdb->terms}
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->terms}.term_id={$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id={$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} related_relationship ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID=related_relationship.object_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} related_term_taxonomy ON related_relationship.term_taxonomy_id=related_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} related_terms ON related_term_taxonomy.term_id=related_terms.term_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND related_terms.term_id<>{$wpdb->terms}.term_id
  AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type='%s'
  AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy='%s'
  AND related_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='%s'
  AND related_terms.term_id=%d
  AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.parent=0
GROUP BY
  {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
SQL;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$post_type,$taxonomy,$related_taxonomy,$term_id);
  $terms = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  return $terms;
}
```

This is used on the category.php page and works great, but I need to now use the same code (ideally) on the child category page?

So for example I have it on a category page of 'trainers', filtered by brand of 'nike' for the custom post type 'products'.

I now need it to show all child categories of 'trainers', also filtered by brand of 'nike' for custom post type of 'products'.

Is there a way to simply add?

```
'category_id'         => '$parent_category',
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Dave

Comment: If anybody has any tips or help on this I'd be very grateful as its been haunting me for a good few days now! Think if I could use `child_of => $parent_category` it would work great?

Comment: Any progress on this Q?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the parent category pretty simple: It's assigned to the object.

```
$cat = get_category( $q_cat );
// Get the ID
echo $cat->category_parent;
```